# AngularJS controllers object is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following code, when the data is saved, the `console.log(user)` is returning `undefined`. What is wrong here?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Name" ng-model="user.name">
<a class="btn btn-link pull-right" ng-click="save(user)">Save</a>
```

Controllers:

```
LControllers.controller( 'InstanceCtrl', ['$scope', 'Instance', 'User',
function ($scope, Instance , User) {
    $scope.user= '';
    $scope.save = function (user) {
        console.log(user)// undefined
        console.log(user.name)       
    };
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15248/

Comment: `user` is undefined or `console.log`

Comment: try to put `user` instead of `use.name` inside `ng-model`

Comment: Is it `undefined` even after you typed something in the text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me , it seems fine

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15248/ `JSFiddle`

after your fill some value in input box, code works fine. 
First time user is an empty string and hence user.name would be undefined.

And yes the right way to declare an object is

```
$scope.name = {};
```

not

```
$scope.name="";
```

Answer (score 0):

I wired up a quick jsFiddle and it seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/tfqytchk/

Of course the first time you press save user is an emptry string and user.name is undefined (I think that's what you're reporting). If you want that to change that behavior then change `$scope.user = '';` to `$scope.user = { name: '' };`

Comment: Your reason seem valid to me, and the downvote is gone. Great.

Answer (score 0):

Do not declare object like this

```
      $scope.user= '';
```

Declare object like

```
      $scope.user= {};
```